# Using italic() with a variable in ggplot2 title expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

When I make a map using `ggplot2` and attempt to italicize part of the figure title using a combination of `expression()` and `italic()` using a string, my map comes out as desired:

```
plottitle <- expression(paste('Example map with ', italic('italics')))

crimes <- data.frame(state = tolower(rownames(USArrests)), USArrests)
states_map <- map_data("state")
map <- ggplot(crimes, aes(map_id = state)) + 
  geom_map(aes(fill = Murder), 
           map = states_map) + 
  expand_limits(x = states_map$long, 
                y = states_map$lat) +
  labs(title = plottitle)

map
```

However, when I try to do the same thing, but use an object instead of a string, the object does not evaluate to the desired string:

```
word <- 'italics'
plottitle2 <- expression(paste('Example map with ', italic(word)))

map <- ggplot(crimes, aes(map_id = state)) + 
  geom_map(aes(fill = Murder), 
           map = states_map) + 
  expand_limits(x = states_map$long, 
                y = states_map$lat) +
  labs(title = plottitle2)

map
```

How can I get the vector `word` to evaluate before applying `italic()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

bquote or substitute should work,

```
 a = 'text' 
 plot(1,1, main=bquote(italic(.(a))))
 plot(1,1, main=substitute(italic(x), list(x=a)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- could you please translate this to my example above? I'm trying to paste together `word` and "Example map with "

Comment: `bquote('Example map with'~italic(.(word)))`

Comment: or `substitute('Example map with'~italic(x), list(x=word))`