# How to italicize part (one or two words) of an axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

Is there any way to change the style of part of an axis title while keep the rest part unchanged? In my case, How could I italicize
"bacteria X" in the y-axis title? To my knowledge, the command `theme(axis.title.y=element_text(face="italic"))` can only change the whole y-aixs title, is it?

```
ggplot(fig1,aes(x=cf,y=Freq,fill=Var1)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
labs(x="Groups",y="No. of bacteria X isolates with corresponding types",fill="Var1") +
theme(axis.title.y=element_text(face="italic"))
```

Answer (score 75):

You could make an expression like this:

```
my_y_title <- expression(paste("No. of ", italic("bacteria X"), " isolates with corresponding types"))
.... + labs(y=my_y_title)
```

Comment: How does this work when part of the title text (inside paste) comes from a variable in the workspace? I noticed that when I bring other variables into the paste, then "paste" is interpreted literally and the title starts with "paste(Chart title..."

Comment: Exactly, our problem too. I've put a suggestion on the `ggplot` GitHub page: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2743

Comment: @Bobby `word <- "the word in italic"` followed by `bquote('Example map with'~italic(.(word)))` found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927984/using-italic-with-a-variable-in-ggplot2-title-expression#31928067

Comment: Calling this variable within `ggtitle()` also will not interpret this correctly. Using in `bquote(custom_title)`, `bquote(.(custom_title))`, or `bquote(~.(custom_title))` do not produce anything close to the desired result. This answer may not be up-to-date and should be edited to provide an example of what you mention, RFelber.

Answer (score 33):

This can be achieved using `element_markdown()` from the [`ggtext`](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext) package.

```r
ggplot(fig1, aes(cf, Freq, fill = Var1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(
    x = "Groups",
    y = "No. of *bacteria X* isolates with corresponding types",
    fill = "Var1"
  ) +
  theme(axis.title.y = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

Notice the `*` around `bacteria X` in the y axis title. Setting `axis.title.y` to `element_markdown` has the effect that the axis title is rendered as markdown. Thus, text inside `*` will be displayed in *italics*.

An even easier solution is using the [`mdthemes`](https://github.com/thomas-neitmann/mdthemes) package which provides themes that interpret text as makrdown out of the box, i.e. no need to call `theme`. Here's an example.

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  mdthemes::md_theme_classic() +
  labs(title = "**Bold Title**", x = "*Italics axis label*")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use mdthemes to allow use of markdown in the titles without changing the theme of the entire graph?

Comment: Please take a look at the [{ggtext}](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext) package for this kind of functionality. Essentially you have to use `ggtext::element_markdown()` rather than `element_text()` inside `theme()`.

Comment: Might be pure coincidence, but it seems as if the author of the mdthemes package (which seems to be awesome) has the same name as you. If it **is** you, a disclaimer is generally considered good practice.

Comment: @ThomasNeitmann Surprisingly, I am unable to italicize using the ggtext::element_markdown() approach, the asterisks don't get rendered but the text isn't italic. Subscript, etc. using <sub>...</sub> works. 
Did anyone else encounter that issue?
UPDATE: Issue has already been reported and will be fixed in the next version: https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext/issues/83

Answer (score 20):

I believe RFelber's suggestion is what you are after. Try this:

```
labs(x="Groups",
     y=expression('No. of'~italic(bacteria X)~'isolates with corresponding types'),
     fill="Var1")
```

I did not need to use the `bquote()` function.  The tildes produce single spaces for terms that are outside of the quotes.

Comment: Thanks - that's a whole lot simpler than using paste or bquote. Whereabouts it the documentation that explains that the tilde works like that?

Comment: What can do you if you don't want spaces where the tildes are?

Comment: Use the paste answer?

Comment: I needed to add backticks to my code. I can't show it exactly here since backticks are the markdown symbol for code on SO and I'm not sure how to escape it for my code, so I'll paste the code plainly: expression('Number of Days in Temperature Range of'~italic(`Phytophthora infestans`)~'in Halifax, VA.')