# How to parse italic in the middle of a string in R?

Tags: r

I have a string such like `x<-"favourable 13q italic('SETA/B') mRNA low"`. In R, how could I get a output using parse as "favourable 13q *SETA/B* mRNA low"? I have tried `parse(text=x)` and it seems not working.

Comment: Where does this input string come from? How did it get that "fake" function call in the first place? Is `italic()` the only part of it you will ever need to parse?

Comment: I need the SETA/B italic in the string as a legend label in a ggplot2 figure

Comment: For use in ggplot2, see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555531/how-to-italicize-part-one-or-two-words-of-an-axis-title helps.  Adding an example of how your use case will help folks answer your question and/or point you to dupes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to italicize part (one or two words) of an axis title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555531/how-to-italicize-part-one-or-two-words-of-an-axis-title)