# Triangle symbol in R how is it written

Tags: r, symbols, x-axis

I'm very new to r
I'm working on ggplot2, Boxplot to be specific
So my plot have a sample name as character and values as numbers
I'm trying to label the x-axis with my samples name and each name has a triangle symbol next to it. This symbol represent the meaning of full gene deletion in the genomic DNA.

for example:

sample 1: bres(triangle symbol)
sample 2: west(triangle symbol)

Is there a function in r for this symbol?
What is the triangle symbol named in R?
How do I write the code for that?
Also how do I write my samples name as italic?

I searched and I couldn't find anyone who experienced this issue as well

Comment: Welcome to SO, Elle! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes_(Unicode_block)):

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  sample = rep(c("bres", "west"), 4),
  y = rnorm(8)
)

ggplot(dat, aes(sample, y)) + geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("bres \u25b2", "west \u25b3"))
```

[image]

Comment: Making the sample names italic is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555531/how-to-italicize-part-one-or-two-words-of-an-axis-title). E.g. replace labels with `labels = c(expression(paste(italic("bres "),"\u25b2")), "west \u25b3")`

Comment: when I tried italic It shows only the first sample labeled but the rest are blank, why? "\u25b3" shows the triangle symbol in the environment window but not in the plot?
df1<-data.fram(f,z)
ggplot(df1)+
geom_boxplot()+
geom_point()+
aes(x=f,y=z,fill=f)+ scale_x_discrete(labels=c(expression(paste(italic("brca\u25b3","west\u25b3")))))

Comment: @Elle Check your parentheses. You didn't correctly copy the code provided by Olympus Mons.