# Embolden substring of object passed through geom_text()

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, fonts

I'm trying to produce a graph and I'd like to bold part of a string of a `geom_text()`. Here's some sample data and a graph:

```
temp <- data.frame(num = c("big"),
                   text = c("small bullet point of text"),
                   col = c("red"))

ggplot(data = temp) +
  lims(x = c(0,100), y = c(0, 100)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 20, y = 50, label = num, color = col), size = 25) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 60, y = 50, label = text), size = 3)
```

[image]

There are two thigns I'd like to do, ideally. First, the most important is that I'd like to embolden the word "bullet" and only that word. Second, if possible I'd like to change the color of the word bullet to "red" , to match that of the word "big".

I've read on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555531/how-to-italicize-part-one-or-two-words-of-an-axis-title) solutions involving the `bold()` function which seems to come from the `grDevices` package but I can't get that to work. It gives the following error when I try the example in that link:

```
> paste("No. of ", bold("bacteria X"), " isolates with corresponding types")
Error in bold("bacteria X") : could not find function "bold"
```

Further, I'd like to be able to call an object from the environment so that I can package this up as a function. I've read about using `bquote()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927984/using-italic-with-a-variable-in-ggplot2-title-expression), but obviously I haven't been able to test that since I can't get `bold()` to work.

So, 1) Why can't I get `bold()` to work? 2) Is `bquote()` with `bold()` the best way to do this? 3) I'd imagine html tags may be an easy way to do this, is there any way to pass a string containing html tags and have ggplot interpert it properly? 4) I don't expect much on the color front as the bold part is what I'm really concerned about, but if you have any suggestions I'll gladly take them. Thanks!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tidyr_0.8.1   stringr_1.3.1 scales_0.5.0  readxl_1.1.0  ggplot2_2.2.1 dplyr_0.7.5  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17     knitr_1.17       bindr_0.1.1      magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.3
 [6] munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 R6_2.2.2         rlang_0.2.1      plyr_1.8.4      
[11] tools_3.4.1      grid_3.4.1       gtable_0.2.0     digest_0.6.12    lazyeval_0.2.0  
[16] assertthat_0.2.0 tibble_1.4.2     bindrcpp_0.2.2   reshape2_1.4.2   purrr_0.2.4     
[21] glue_1.2.0       labeling_0.3     stringi_1.1.7    compiler_3.4.1   pillar_1.1.0    
[26] cellranger_1.1.0 pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568453/using-different-font-styles-in-annotate-ggplot2) might be relevant.  I haven't seen an easy way to add different colors within the string, though, other than adding things in separate `annotate()` calls.

Comment: @aosmith that solution worked for at least getting it to bold the text. I can't seem to get it to call from the environment though. if I do `a <- "boldedword"` and then run it as `paste("this is the ", bold(a), " here")` it gives the same result as the unquoted version `paste("this is the ", bold("a"), " here")`. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working with plotmath in **ggplot2** confounds me every time, especially when trying to pass in a variable.

I *think* I got things to work how you want them, complete with one bold word with a separate color passed from a variable.  It involves `deparse()` **and** `bquote()` **and** `bold()` along with `phantom()`.  Phew.

The `phantom()` holds the place of the words you *don't* want to show with the specific color, so it takes two `annotate()` layers to make the whole expression using different colors.

```
a = "bullet"
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
    annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, 
             label = deparse(bquote(phantom(small)~bold(.(a))~phantom(point~of~text))),
             colour = "red", parse = TRUE) +
    annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, 
             label = deparse(bquote(small~phantom(bold(.(a)))~point~of~text)),
             colour = "black", parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

**Adding facets**

I feel certain there is an easier approach to facets and "a" as a vector but this is what I've come up with on a Friday afternoon. :-D

My approach is to loop through the (character) vector and make a new variable with all the deparsing and bquoting and such.  The faceting variable is part of the text dataset.

```
dat = data.frame(x = c(4, 4),
                 y = c(25, 25),
                 a = c("bullet", "shell"),
                 am = c(0, 1) )

dat$a1 = sapply(as.character(dat$a), 
                       function(x) deparse(bquote(phantom(small)~bold(.(x))~phantom(point~of~text))), 
                simplify = TRUE)
dat$a2 = sapply(as.character(dat$a), 
                       function(x) deparse(bquote(small~phantom(bold(.(x)))~point~of~text)), 
                simplify = TRUE)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg) ) +
    geom_text(data = dat, aes(x, y, label = a1), color = "red", parse = TRUE) +
    geom_text(data = dat, aes(x, y, label = a2), color = "black", parse = TRUE) +
    facet_wrap(~am)
```

[image]

## Working with multiple variables

Last, if you need to get characters pasted together with colors and font style and such using multiple columns in a vector you an do so.  My approach involves loping through every row in the dataset, working with the columns that contain the label info.  Note I'm working with characters (not factors) to avoid problems.

I pull in the helper function `pmap()` from package **purrr** for rowwise work.

If colors need to be different for the highlighted word in each facet you can define the colors in the data.frame and use `scale_color_identity` to use those colors.

```
dat = data.frame(x = c(4, 4),
                 y = c(25, 25),
                 a = c("bullet", "shells"),
                 b = c("point of text", "on the beach"),
                 am = c(0, 1),
                 color = c("red", "purple"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

dat$a1 = pmap_chr(dat, function(a, b, ...) 
                deparse(bquote(phantom(small)~bold(.(a))~phantom(.(b))) ) )

dat$a2 = pmap_chr(dat, function(a, b, ...) 
     deparse(bquote(small~phantom(bold(.(a)))~.(b))))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg) ) +
     geom_text(data = dat, aes(x, y, label = a1, color = color), parse = TRUE) +
     geom_text(data = dat, aes(x, y, label = a2), color = "black", parse = TRUE) +
     facet_wrap(~am) +
     scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. I'm going to work with it over the weekend. I'll be back soon with either a question or your check mark.

Comment: Sidebar: do you know if this works when `a` is a vector? In my actual use case, I'm faceting on a third variable but it seems like `bquote()` doesn't want to produce the output in the way I need it. When I tried to replace `a` in your code with `vs` or `mtcars$vs` it gives the same error: `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): label, colour`

Comment: I've got a feeling there's something useful in here, but I haven't quite figured it out yet. Playing with it to see what might work https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Plotmath

Comment: @seeellayewhy See my edits.  But, yes, it seems like there is likely a simpler way out there.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Truly the best support I've ever gotten on here, wish I had more to offer than just a check and a vote! My use case has even more nuances (vectorized non-bolded text as well) so I'm off to figure that part out but I'd have never gotten started without your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
my_text <- expression(paste("small ", bold("bullet"), " point of text"))
ggplot() +
  lims(x = c(0,100), y = c(0, 100)) + 
  annotate('text', x=25, y=25, label=my_text)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it and it gave the following error message: `Error in stats::complete.cases(df[, vars, drop = FALSE]) : 
  invalid 'type' (expression) of argument`. Did a little googling but I can't quite figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @seeellayewhy Install the latest development version of ggplot (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2).  It will work.